# Put imshow of opencv into panel of windows forms?

Tags: winforms, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am writing a project using openCV visual c++ for my school with windows forms, i was wondering can i put my imshow function on panel of myform?

Comment: You can't. Just convert the Mat to Bitmap, and draw a regular Bitmap in your windows form

Comment: ok then i knew about that (Mat to Bitmap) i just didn't wanted to use cpu too much, all in all thank you.